# Tailwind grid columns template with collapsable items

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have this code:

```
<div>
   <div :class="'mt-4 gap-4 grid grid-cols-' + gridColumns">
       <collapsable-item
           v-for="(row, i) in filteredRows" :key="'row' + i"
              class="w-72"
              :row="row"
           />
   </div>
</div>
```

My problem is: when open a collapsable item, the other items in the same row give the opened item height.
Of course, the gridColumns in the class is calculated computed value.

What I would like:

[image]